# Getting Cors error in next js 13.4 app when trying to fetch json data

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, cors

Here is the search/page where actual fetch request is situated.

```
import { useSearchParams } from "next/navigation";
import Footer from "../components/Footers";
import Header from "../components/header";

import { format } from "date-fns";
import InfoCard from "../components/InfoCard";
import Image from "next/image";


// export default async function searchRes() {

// };

// const searchRes = async () => {
//   const resultss = await fetch("https://www.jsonkeeper.com/b/YVMX");
//   const resultsss = await resultss.json();
//   return resultsss;
// };


 export default async function Search() {
  // const resultsss = await searchRes();

  const searchParams = useSearchParams();
  const locations = searchParams.get("locations");
  const startDate = searchParams.get("startDate");
  const endDate = searchParams.get("endDate");
  const noOfGuests = searchParams.get("noOfGuests");
  const formatStartDate = format(new Date(startDate), "dd MMMM");
  const formatEndDate = format(new Date(endDate), "dd MMMM");
  const days = `${formatStartDate} - ${formatEndDate}`;

  
  
    const resultss = await fetch("https://www.jsonkeeper.com/b/YVMX"
    , {
      method: 'GET',
      // mode: 'no-cors',
      // headers: {
      //   "Access-Control-Allow-Headers" : "Content-Type",
      //   "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
      //   "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "OPTIONS,POST,GET",
      // },
    }
    )
    // .then((res)=>res.json);

    const resultsss = await resultss.json();
    console.log(resultsss);

  // const resultsss = await resultss();
  
  

  // const resultsss = await searchRes();

  return (
    <div>
      <Header
        placeholder={`${locations}  | ${days} | ${noOfGuests} guest(s)`}
      />
      <main className="mx-3">
        <p className="text-xs md:text-sm mt-3">
          50+ Stays {days} for {noOfGuests} guest(s)
        </p>
        <h1 className="text-lg  md:text-2xl  font-bold mt-2 mb-5">
          Stays in {locations}
        </h1>
        <div className="mb-5 mr-3">
          <button className="text-xs  md:text-sm rounded-full px-3 py-2 border-gray-300 border hover:shadow-md  active:bg-slate-100 mr-2 mb-2  ">
            Free Cancellation
          </button>
          <button className="text-xs md:text-sm rounded-full px-2 py-2 border-gray-300 border hover:shadow-md  active:bg-slate-100 mr-2 mb-2   ">
            Type of place
          </button>
          <button className="text-xs md:text-sm rounded-full px-2 py-2 border-gray-300 border hover:shadow-md  active:bg-slate-100 mr-2 mb-2   ">
            Price
          </button>
          <button className="text-xs md:text-sm rounded-full px-2 py-2 border-gray-300 border hover:shadow-md  active:bg-slate-100 mr-2 mb-2   ">
            Dormitory
          </button>
          <button className="text-xs md:text-sm rounded-full px-2 py-2 border-gray-300 border hover:shadow-md  active:bg-slate-100 mr-2 mb-2  ">
            More filters
          </button>
        </div>
        <div className=" ">
          {resultsss?.map(
            ({
              img,
              key,
              location,
              title,
              description,
              star,
              price,
              total,
            }) => (
              <InfoCard
                key={total}
                img={img}
                location={location}
                title={title}
                description={description}
                star={star}
                price={price}
                total={total}
              />
            )
          )}
        </div>
      </main>
      <Footer />
    </div>
  );
}

// export default Search;

// https://jsonkeeper.com/b/Z5I9
// for indian currency https://www.jsonkeeper.com/b/YVMX
// https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/
```

Next.config

```
const nextConfig = {};

module.exports = {
  async headers() {
    return [
      {
        // matching all API routes
        source: "/api/:path*",
        headers: [
          { key: "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", value: "true" },
          { key: "Access-Control-Allow-Origin", value: "*" },
          {
            key: "Access-Control-Allow-Methods",
            value: "GET,OPTIONS,PATCH,DELETE,POST,PUT",
          },
          {
            key: "Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
            value:
              "X-CSRF-Token, X-Requested-With, Accept, Accept-Version, Content-Length, Content-MD5, Content-Type, Date, X-Api-Version",
          },
        ],
      },
    ];
  },
  images: {
    domains: ["links.papareact.com"],
  },
};
nextConfig;
```

Everything is working fine when cors extension is enabled on chrome.
Also I am  using fetch to pull data from same source in page i.. under the app and it is working very fine. see its code as well.

```
import LargeCard from "./components/LargeCard";
import MediumCard from "./components/MediumCard";
import SmallCard from "./components/SmallCard";
import Footer from "./components/Footers";

import Header from "./components/header";

export default async function Home() {
  const res1 = await fetch("https://www.jsonkeeper.com/b/IJK5");
  const res2 = await fetch("https://www.jsonkeeper.com/b/OJBH");
  const data1 = await res1.json();
  const data11 = data1;
  const data2 = await res2.json();
  const data22 = data2;

 

  return (
    <>
    
      <Header />
      <Banner />

      {/* SmallCardSection */}
      <div className="  max-w-7xl mx-auto mt-5  pb-5  ">
        <h2 className=" ml-5 text-2xl font-bold">Explore Nearby</h2>
        <div className=" grid grid-cols-1 sm:grid-cols-2 lg:grid-cols-3 xl:grid-cols-4  ">
          {data11?.map((item) => (
            <SmallCard
              key={item.key}
              img={item.img}
              location={item.location}
              distance={item.distance}
            />
          ))}
        </div>
      </div>
      {/* MediumCardSection */}
      <section className="  max-w-7xl mx-auto mt-5   pb-5  ">
        <h2 className=" text-2xl font-bold ml-5">Live Anywhere</h2>
        <div className="  relative flex flex-row space-x-3 overflow-scroll scrollbar-hide pl-5">
          {data22?.map((item) => (
            <MediumCard img={item.img} key={item.id} title={item.title} />
          ))}
        </div>
      </section>
      <div className="max-w-7xl mx-auto pl-5 pr-5 lg:pr-10 ">
        <LargeCard
          title={"The Greatest Outdoors"}
          description={"Wishlists curated by Airbnb."}
          buttonText={"Get Inspired"}
        />
      </div>
      <div className=" ">
        <Footer />
      </div>
    </>
  );
}
```

I am making this project for study purpose so, not having that much knowledge

Comment: If everything is working thine what is the problem exactly?

Comment: @kevinSpaceyIsKeyserSöze i am getting cors error, with chrome extension code is working, but it was not like it supposed to be

Comment: As far as I understand, the cors extension disables cors so it's working. But if you don't use the cors extensioin you get an error? You can't handle this on client side. Your server needs to set the cors header not the client.

Comment: Yes, i am getting error after cors extension disables, you help is appriciated if you can suggest changes in code to make it work

Comment: Do you have your own server side code? You can't control cors from your client

Answer (score 1):

Can you add destination key for your api domain?

```
// next.config.js
module.exports = {
    async rewrites() {
        return [
          {
            source: '/api/:path*',
            destination: 'https://www.jsonkeeper.com/:path*',
          }
        ]
    }
};
```

Comment: Actually, api domain doesn't have any key, code in nex.config is compied to try out if that works

Answer (score 0):

I'm having problems accessing the API from the frontend. but strangely, it can work in postman or in nodejs.
I have tried various sources as a solution by adding cors settings in config.next.js, in middleware to adding them directly to the API. but the results are still an error, still not accessible in the browser. So the current solution is to change from using an App Router to a Pages Router. and finally successful

```
   import type { NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse } from 'next'

type Data = {
  name: string
}

export const allowCors = (fn: Function) => async (req: NextApiRequest,
  res: NextApiResponse) => {

  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');


  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', 'true')
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,OPTIONS,PATCH,DELETE,POST,PUT')
  res.setHeader(
    'Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'authorization , X-CSRF-Token, X-Requested-With, Accept, Accept-Version, Content-Length, Content-MD5, Content-Type, Date, X-Api-Version')
  if (req.method === 'OPTIONS') {
    res.status(200).end()
    return
  }
  return await fn(req, res)
}
```

implementation on API like this

```
...    
export default allowCors(handler);
```